# foreach by quantity in laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel

I develop a ticketing system which user have to choose the quantity of ticket category. I want to save the record to database by the total of quantity. But it seems to be failed. I end up only save the record by category id. Here is the result when I try to return it.
[image: Debug]

and this is my code in controller.

```
public function ticket_checkout(Request $request)
    {
        $ctg_id = $request->cat_id;
        $price = $request->price;
        $name = $request->name;
        $qty = $request->qty;
        // return count($qty);

        $data = [];
        $i = 0;
        foreach($qty as $item){
            if($qty[$i] != 0){
                $data[] = [
                    "ctg_id" => $ctg_id[$i],
                    "price" => $price[$i],
                    "qty" => $item,
                ];
            }
            $i++;
        }

        return $data;
        Ticket_checkout::insert($data);
        // return $qty;
        return view('ticket.index', compact('data','qty'));
    }
```

I wonder if I missing something here? I tried to do looping 'for' by quantity inside the 'foreach' but it seems not working too.

Comment: have you got name as fillable on the ticket checkout model?

Comment: Why you have `return $data;` statement before the database update

Comment: return for debugging